# malloc with a multidimensional array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, tree, malloc

I'm working on a dictionary whose structure is:

```
typedef union _dict {
    union _dict * children[M];
    list * words[M];
} dict;
```

Initialisation:

```
dict *d = (dict*) malloc(sizeof(dict));
```

I'm trying to do the following:

```
dict *temp;
temp = d;

temp=temp->children[0];
temp=temp->children[0];
```

The `first temp->children[0]` works but not the second. I'm trying to understand why. I think it's a memory allocation problem.

**Edit 1:**
I've tried the following code :

```
dict *d = (dict*) malloc(sizeof(dict));

dict *temp;
temp = d;

dict *d2 = (dict*) malloc(sizeof(dict));
temp->children[0] = d2;

temp = temp->children[0];
temp = temp->children[0];
temp = temp->children[0];
```

That now works, but I don't understand why... I mean, i don't have allowed some memory for next children.

**Edit 2:**
So now, I would like to use this in my algorithm. The code block where I am stuck is the following:

```
list *l;
if (temp->words[occur] != NULL) {
    /* ... */
}
else {
    l = list_new();
    temp->words[occur] = (list*) malloc(sizeof(list));
    temp->words[occur] = l;
}
list_append(l,w);
list_print(l);
```

If I put a `temp->words[occur] = NULL;` before this block, the word is successfully added, but a new list is created each time the algorith is used. I would like to add my word to the previously created list, assuming it exists.

A `bzero((void*)d, sizeof(dict));` instruction is used after the dict initialisation.

Comment: Thats because the first children is implicitly created `union _dict * children[M];` but each element in that array is not allocated automatically. I believe is the issue. Therefore your second is using a "child" that hasn't had a `_dict` space created for it.

Comment: In your second code block: The first assignment will fill `temp` with a valid `dict`. The second will fill it with garbage. The third should fail because no `children` exists in the garbage.

Comment: So each time I explore the next children I must alloc a dict to it?

Comment: That's a very unorthodox structure.  Why a union and not a struct?  Why are the arrays 'inside' the union. (Did you devise the union or did a sadistic tutor give it to you?)  What are you hoping to do with your '`temp = temp->children[0]`' assignments?  Why do you need M children (if M > 1)?  How do you know whether a given member of the union holds a `list *` or other `union _dict *` values?

Comment: A tutor gave that `union` to me :)
With `temp->children[0]` I want to access the next `children`.
`M` is set to 8, I need `M children` to put words in my dictionnary depending on the number of occurency of each letter. For each `dict` i have 9 `children` and 9 `words`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in that the first `children` is created as a pointer to a `dict` like: `union _dict * children[M];` but each element in that array is not allocated automatically. Therefore, your second call is using a "child" that hasn't had `dict` space created for it.

If you want it to work properly something like this should solve the issue:

```
typedef union _dict {
    union _dict * children[M];
    list * words[M];
} dict;

dict *temp = (dict*) malloc(sizeof(dict));

//allocate space for child, and reassign to it
temp->children[0] = (dict*) malloc(sizeof(dict));
temp = temp->children[0];

//allocate space for child, and reassign to it
temp->children[0] = (dict*) malloc(sizeof(dict));
temp = temp->children[0];

//etc...
```

Each child has to be allocated memory, or you just get trash and/or seg faults.

Comment: OK, I get it. And the same corresponding `malloc` for `words`, I guess?

Comment: general rule: if its dynamically created, you need to allocate and deallocate its memory (some exceptions like some built-ins).

Comment: After the initialisation of my `dict d`, I'm using a `bzero((void*)d, sizeof(dict));` instruction. I would like to know what extactly is zero-ed and on how many levels.

Answer (score 2):

At first in `temp` you have a valid pointer to an object (allocated with malloc). Then you assign an uninitialized pointer to `temp` and attempt to dereference it with the expected consequences.

Answer (score 2):

`children` is never initialised, so it contains whatever garbage was in memory before. After the first `temp = temp->children[0]`, temp is a pointer to unknown territory.

Answer (score 0):

```
temp=temp->children[0];
```

You never assign any value for `temp->children[0]`. So after this line of code, `temp` contains garbage.

Answer (score 0):

i think 2nd time usage might give you segmantation fault.

see

```
dict *d = (dict*) malloc(sizeof(dict));  // once you have malloc



dict *temp;
temp = d;

temp=temp->children[0];  // that is going to use here
```

for using 2nd time you havent malloc..? right so beffre to use in that way you should malloc like

```
 d->children[0] = (dict*) malloc(sizeof(dict));
```

Comment: I now have allocated memory for the first children (see edit on my post). I don't understand why it seems to work for the next children.